# Angular 4 How the parent component can know that the children's route is open

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have structure of routes:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LibraryComponent
   ,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LibraryPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'online-learning',
        component: LibraryCoursesPageComponent   
      },
      {
        path: 'events',
        component: LibraryEventsPageComponent,
        }

    // another children
      ]
```

}

For example:
If my current route 'online-learning' or another route of children, **how the parent component can know that the children's route is open**?

May be is some method or value  in `ActivatedRoute`.

*P.S. Is there solution without parsing url?*

Thanks!